# MySql query syntax error from hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

the following query is not getting executed. it is throwing error. i am not able to identify the error. its is generated by hibenate.
Driver class org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver, dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
please help me waht is the error.

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb

```
select this_.Student_Id as Student1_8_0_, this_.student Name as student2_8_0_, 
       this_.address as address8_0_, this_.Father Name as Father4_8_0_, 
       this_.Mother Name as Mother5_8_0_, this_.Primary Contact No as Primary6_8_0_,
       this_.Secondary Contact No as Secondary7_8_0_, this_.Occupation as Occupation8_0_, 
       this_.Mode_Id as Mode9_8_0_, this_.Class_Id as Class10_8_0_, 
       this_.Route_No as Route11_8_0_ 
from Tbl_Student this_
```

if i run as `select * from Tbl_Student` like this it is working fine.

Comment: show your code and error/exception.

Comment: If you fire this query directly to Mysql what error comes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use back-ticks to enclose column names separated with spaces:

```
`this_`.`Father Name`, ..
```

Comment: Yes i got error because of this spaces in the column name.thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is that code? Is it your HQL statement or is it the SQL statement generated by Hibernate?

If it is your HQL statement:
You have to use the names of the properties, i. e. the Java member names as column names.

If it is the SQL statement generated by Hibernate:
There is probably an error in your mapping, and you used a space instead of an underscore in Father_Name, Mother_Name, Primary_Contact_No and Secondary_Contact_No.